# Highlighting regions in ggplot2 barplot fulfilling a condition

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a horizontal barplot using ggplot2 and highlight regions satisfying a particular criteria.

In this case, if any "Term" for point "E15.5-E18.5_up_down" has more than twice the number of samples compared to point "P22-P29_up_down" and vice-versa, highlight that label or region.

I have a dataframe in following format:

```
CLID    CLSZ    GOID    NodeSize    SampleMatch Phyper  Padj    Term    Ont SampleKeys
E15.5-E18.5_up_down 1364    GO:0007568  289 20  0.141830716154421   1   aging   BP  ENSMUSG00000049932 ENSMUSG00000046352 ENSMUSG00000078249 ENSMUSG00000039428 ENSMUSG00000014030 ENSMUSG00000039323 ENSMUSG00000026185 ENSMUSG00000027513 ENSMUSG00000023224 ENSMUSG00000037411 ENSMUSG00000020429 ENSMUSG00000020897 ENSMUSG00000025486 ENSMUSG00000021477 ENSMUSG00000019987 ENSMUSG00000023067 ENSMUSG00000031980 ENSMUSG00000023070 ENSMUSG00000025747 ENSMUSG00000079017
E15.5-E18.5_up_down 1364    GO:0006397  416 3   0.999999969537913   1   mRNA processing BP  ENSMUSG00000027510 ENSMUSG00000021210 ENSMUSG00000027951
P22-P29_up_down 476 GO:0007568  289 11  0.0333771791166823  1   aging   BP  ENSMUSG00000049932 ENSMUSG00000037664 ENSMUSG00000026879 ENSMUSG00000026185 ENSMUSG00000026043 ENSMUSG00000060600 ENSMUSG00000022508 ENSMUSG00000020897 ENSMUSG00000028702 ENSMUSG00000030562 ENSMUSG00000021670
P22-P29_up_down 476 GO:0006397  416 2   0.998137879564768   1   mRNA processing BP  ENSMUSG00000024007 ENSMUSG00000039878
```

reduced to (only those terms which are necessary for plotting):

```
CLID    SampleMatch Term
E15.5-E18.5_up_down 20  aging
P22-P29_up_down 2   mRNA processing
E15.5-E18.5_up_down 3   mRNA processing
P22-P29_up_down 11  aging
```

I would prefer a general approach which will work with any condition, not just the one I need for this scenario. One way I imagined is to use `sapply` for each pair of CLID/Term and create another column which stores if the criteria is fulfilled as a boolean, but still I cannot find a way to highlight the values. What would be the most efficient way to achieve this ?

Pseudo-code for my approach:

```
for(i in CLID) {
    for(k in CLID) {
        if (Term[i] == Term[k]) {
            condition = check(Term[i], Term[k]) #check if the SampleMatch count for any for any CLID/Term pair is significantly higher compared to corresponding CLID/Term pair
            if (condition == True) {
                highlight(term)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In the end I want something like this (highlighting the label or column): 
[image]

or like this: [Highlight data individually with facet_grid in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485979/highlight-data-individually-with-facet-grid-in-r).

Comment: Please see this question with answers: [How to change the font size and color of x-axis and y-axis label in a scatterplot with plot function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839731/vary-colors-of-axis-labels-in-r-based-on-another-variable)

Comment: @skhan8, Thank you for the answer. While I can answer this question, it might be duplication. Should I delete it, mark it as an duplicate or answer it myself, even-tough it is a similar answer to the question thread. Can any moderator help ?